# Graph - modelling node with two parents

Tags: algorithm, search, design-patterns, tree, graph-theory

I have a graph with nodes, and I need to follow from leaf to root, and to know the single path - even when there are two parents for some of the nodes. Example - `Child` is the same concept, that can belong to `Parent 1` or `Parent 2`. `Leaf 1` and `Leaf 2` are also concepts that belong to `Child` either through `Parent 1` or `Parent 2`. So it can happen that some nodes under `Leaf 1` have parent structure of `Parent 1 -> Child -> Leaf 1 -> *` or `Parent 2 -> Child -> Leaf 1 -> *`. If modeled using the following approach, that information is lost:

[image]

So far, I have a few approaches to disambiguate this:

First one is duplicating all the nodes - everything is separated (at a cost of duplication).

[image]

Second one is using labels on the edges - but still duplicating some of the nodes:

[image]

And the third one is also using labels - without duplicating nodes, but labels are further away from parents:

[image]

Is there any other solution for this? Are there any best practices in modelling this kind of graph?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to follow from leaf to root,

A root implies that you have a tree.

> there are two parents for some of the nodes

This means that you do NOT have a tree.

A graph that is not a tree does not have a root.  So you cannot follow from a leaf to a root, since there is no root.

In comments you say that the graph is the result of merging two trees.  If you discard the original 2 tree structure, then there is no way to recover it from the merged graph.

Comment: In my use-case there will be one node that is parent of `Parent 1` and `Parent 2` - this is the one that I call root in my question (it is not a root in a "tree" sense). Still - have to find out which of those modeling approaches is the best one (or something completely new). Complete split seems easier when adding nodes (at expense of duplication), and labels seems easier when querying (at expense of complex update logic).

Comment: The approach is as I have described.  If you want the paths to multiple nodes all you have to do is run your path finding algorithm multiple times, once for each destination.  There is absolutely no need to "split" or "duplicate" or modify your graph in any way.

Comment: The thing is, it is actually a tree structure expressed in a graph (so not to duplicate some mid-nodes that are actually same concept). I guess that means that splitting the nodes is the best option here - to store Child and Leaf1, Leaf2 two times (just attached to different parent) - so that I have proper tree structure. Since, I need to know if some of the sub-leaf nodes is from Parent1 or from Parent2 - it cannot belong to both at the same time.

Comment: You seem to be talking about a different problem than the one presented in the original question.  Perhaps you should rewrite the question so it accurately describes the entire problem?

Comment: Maybe something like this:  I have a problem about related concepts ( detailed description of problem )  How should I best represent this as a graph, so that I can use a standard graph algorithm?

Comment: I see now that I did not express myself good enough in the question. It is basically 2 tree structures that I represented as single graph (where I merged nodes that share the same name and concept - Child, Leaf 1 and Leaf 2) - and then I want to know how to still know which of the parent nodes this children belong to. But I think I will just split it back to tree structure...

Comment: If you discard the original 2 tree structure, then there is no way to recover it from the merged graph.

Answer (score 0):

As you consider that a child actually belongs to only one of the multiple parents, you should duplicate. The duplicate child is not *exactly* a duplicate, because its relatives are not the same: the parent is not the same, and although the children are look-alikes, they are not the same, because their grandparent is not the same. So actually there are no *real* duplicates.

If however each node has more attributes than just the links to parent/children, then you could store those attributes in a separate object, and have the nodes refer to it. That way you can have multiple nodes that share the same properties:

[image]

The added circles in this diagram are not to be regarded as nodes of the graph, but collections of properties to which a node may refer.